# What is the utility of HTML thead function and the difference of making up tables with and without it?

Tags: html

What is the utility of the thead function to make up a table, when you can simply use the tr,th, and td functions? What is the difference between making up a table with and without the thead function and its subordinate ones (tbody and tfoot)?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp below "Definition and Usage" there is what you are looking for

Comment: `thead` represents the abstract notion of a table header and allows for styling at this level. In a table with a header containing multiple lines you might wish to style the border of the header as a whole in a particular fashion (eg. fat borders) and the `thead` element is the hook to do so. An equivalent effect can be obtained by styling the header's `th` elements appropriately but it is more cumbersome and error-prone as much as it is less readable and maintainable (try it on a toy example).

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML  element defines a set of rows defining the head of the columns of the table.

As it is written on mozillas developer guide site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

---

From the developers view it doesn't makes much difference to just use `tr`, `th`, and `td` markup.

Generally using `thead` makes the markup **more accessible** and easier to understand for search-engines or screen-readers.